# How to reset saved password on IE server side

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, change-password, reset-password

Some of my users have the problem that their browser doesn't update their saved password after they change it on my web application. I know that they can delete their cookies or something else to reset the saved password but i want to do this automatically on server side. Modern browser like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox are already able to do this but the users with Internet Explorer (IE) having some troubles with the password change.

I've already tried to activate / deactivate the autocomplete attribute in HTML to solve this problem.

Comment: The user has to do that themselves. Saved form data in the browser has nothing to do with server-side (cookies, etc.) code and thankfully cannot be manipulated!

Comment: Hi, Tools>Internet Options>content tab, has the user's IE form filling options... In your web page you need to add external.autocompleteSaveForm() for MSIE browsers to prompt to insert or update entries in its form-filling store. 
example link: http://www.debugtheweb.com/test/passwordautocomplete.asp

see 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/09/10/why-wont-ie-remember-my-login-info/
and

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/04/08/forcing-internet-explorer-to-forget-to-not-remember/